# Delete spawning list objects consistently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Already 2 days I'm trying to solve this problem but I can't.I'm trying to delete the unlimited spawning barriers consistently when they are collide with the boundary.The barriers are made from 5 cubes.Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
public List<GameObject> spawning=new List<GameObject>();
public Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[5];

public GameObject barrier;
public GameObject boundary;


void Start()
{
StartCoroutine (SpawnBarrier());
}

void Update()
{
if(true)
{
    foreach (GameObject move in spawning) 
        move.transform.Translate (0f, 0f, -0.1f);
}

}


IEnumerator SpawnBarrier(){

yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);

while (true) {


    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {

        spawning.Add (Instantiate (barrier, positions [i],   Quaternion.identity)as GameObject);



    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);

}
}
```

Comment: Avoid `while(true)` and `if(true)` in your code

Comment: @MarkBenovsky Nothing wrong with that since OP is yielding in that loop with `WaitForSeconds`

Answer (score 1):

Your barriers are marked as `isTrigger` on their colliders therefore you can use `OnTriggerEnter` to detect when any of the barriers collides with the boundary.

You need to create new script, lets call that `BoundaryDetector` and attach it to the barrier prefab so that every instance of the barrier will have this script attached to it.

When `OnTriggerEnter` is called, check if the trigger is made by the boundary. This can be done by checking for the "Player" tag since boundary is tagged as Player in your screenshot. If the detected trigger tag is "Player", first remove the spawning from the spawning List then `Destroy` it.

The `BoundaryDetector` script is as below (Must be attached to the barrier prefab):

```
ScriptFromYourQuestion yourInstancingSript;

void Start()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("NameOfObjectScriptInYourQuestionIsAttachedTo");
    yourInstancingSript = obj.GetComponent<ScriptFromYourQuestion>();
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //Detect if we collided with the boundary
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        //Remove Self/barrier from the List
        yourInstancingSript.spawning.Remove(this.gameObject);


        //Delete Self/barrier 
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Note: The `ScriptFromYourQuestion` should be replaced with the name of the script in your question.

**MUST DO**:

To get the code above working, the following changes must be made in the `Update` function of the script from your question:

**1**.You must attach `Rigidbody` to at-least one of the Objects (boundary or barrier). In this case, I suggest you do so to the barrier prefab.

**2**.You must remove `move.transform.Translate (0f, 0f, -0.1f);` and replace it with `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and use that to move your barries because you have now attached `Rigidbody` to your barries and this is the proper way to move a `Rigidbody` Object.

Maybe something like this:

Your Update function in the code form your quesion should looks something like this:

```
public float speed = 100.0f;

void Update()
{
    if (true)
    {
        foreach (GameObject move in spawning)
        {
            //Get Rigidbody component 
            Rigidbody rb = move.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            //Calculate Z-axis pos to move to
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            pos = pos.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            //Move with Rigidbody
            rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have an infinite loop `while true` that you're not breaking out of. Instead you should add a counter. You haven't explained what you want to do but my example is that it will breakout once it completes 10 instantiations of 5 blocks.

```
IEnumerator SpawnBarrier(){
    spawnCount=0
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);
    while (true) {
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            spawning.Add (Instantiate (barrier, positions [i],   Quaternion.identity)as GameObject);
        }
        if (++spawnCount==10)
        {
            break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need a counter that break out my loop,the spawning barriers must be unlimited. I just want to delete the barrier when it touch the boundary,but i can't because I'm out of index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood corrently, you want to destroy barriers that collided with some kind of boundary?

### If the 'boundary' is the visible screen space

In this case, we can assume that, once the object is invisible to `MainCamera` it can be counted as *out of the boundary*. Keeping that in mind, we can use `OnBecameInvisible()` method, which is method (*or message, as stated in Unity Scripting API*) called by `MonoBehaviour` class:

```
// A piece of barrier that gets destroyed once out of screen
public sealed class BarrierPiece : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Called once the object is no longer visible to any (scene editor included) camera
    private void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: if you have more than one `Camera` in your scene, the object must be invisible to all of the cameras in order for the `OnBecameInvisible()` to be called.

### If the 'boundary' is other object

In this case, there are many approaches based on your game:

- Create `GameObject` with `Rigidbody` component and add a script which would have `OnTriggerEnter(...)` method and destroy colliding barriers in it.
- (**Inefficient**) have two static `Vector2` variables, one for `pivotPosition`, other for `maximumOffset` (this one should be squared for faster calculations). Then, have script on each of the barriers and in `Update()` checks whether the object's squared distance to the `pivotPosition` is greater than `maximumOffset` and call `Destroy(gameObject)` if the condition is `true`.
- (others) ...

Those are two that came up quickly in my mind.

Hope this helps!

## EDIT

Didn't look at the images...

So for your solution, you would need to assign `Rigidbody` component to the `Boundary` and add `BoxCollider` component on all of the barriers. Now, create a tag, called `Barrier` and tag all the barriers with it. Create a script:

```
// Destroys barriers on collision
public sealed class BarrierBoundary : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Called once the script is created
    // Checks if the object has Rigidbody component attached
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Assert(GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.tag == "Barrier")
            Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```

(The code wasn't tested, so it can have some typos.)

Now, assign the script to the `Boundary`. And voila! Barriers are destroyed once hitting the boundary.
Hope (again) this helps!